# iDRAC 6 Express setup secured SMTP alert

Tags: drac

I have iDRAC 6 Express but I can't seem find any documentations outlining how to setup Email Alert to send through an secure SMTP server (ie Gmail's SMTP server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the documentation and suchlike, it appears that iDRAC6 does not support SMTP-auth at all.

Comment: Even the full iDRAC 6 (ie., not Express) doesn't have the option for authenticating an SMTP server.

Comment: Blah, that's unfortunate. Does anyone know if OpenManager support authenticated SMTP? (Though I'm hesitated to install it due to performance problem...)

Comment: It's 2012 and seemingly there's still no auth options. I'd not call that unfortunate I'd call it an epic fail :)